# Initializing and setting Material UI TextField state as a number

Tags: reactjs, graphql-js

I am working on a workout logger, where users can log their sets for exercises. I am using the MERNG stack for this project. Currently, I am working on the validation for logging a set on the front end. This will ask users for these: exercise name(String), weight(Float), reps(Int) and notes(String - optional) in a form. The problem I am having, is initializing and setting the weight and reps in their respected types. This is the initial states I have set for these fields:

```
{
    exerciseName: "",
    weight: "", 
    reps: "",
    notes: "",
}
```

I realize that this will return the weight and reps as Strings, so I tried this as well (although, I don't want fields to have a weight and rep already entered for them, in case they forget to input these themselves and add it to their logs).

```
{
    exerciseName: "",
    weight: 0,
    reps: 0,
    notes: "",
  }
```

This approach works to a certain degree, as the console logs them as Numbers but when the user changes this in the TextField(Material UI), they end up getting submitted as Strings anyway. Therefore, I receive the 400 status code from my backend, as these should be a Float and an Int. How can I achieve the result of initializing and setting these values as numbers only, so no error fires?

**Form**

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({}); 

const { onChange, onSubmit, values } = useForm(registerSet, { // Uses a hook for forms
    exerciseName: "",
    weight: "",
    reps: "",
    notes: "",
});

return (
  <form
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    id="addSetForm"
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
  >
    <TextField
      name="exerciseName"
      label="Exercise Name"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      select
      className={classes.formInput}
      value={values.exerciseName}
      error={errors.exerciseName ? true : false}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      <MenuItem key="Bench Press" value="Bench Press">
        Bench Press
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem key="Deadlift" value="Deadlift">
        Deadlift
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem key="Squat" value="Squat">
        Squat
      </MenuItem>
    </TextField>

    <Grid container spacing={1} className={classes.formInput}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField
          name="weight"
          label="Weight"
          type="number"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          value={values.weight}
          error={errors.weight ? true : false}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField
          name="reps"
          label="Reps"
          type="number"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          value={values.reps}
          error={errors.reps ? true : false}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </form>
)
```

**formHooks.js (useForm)**

```
export const useForm = (callback, initialState = {}) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        callback();
    };

    return {
        onChange,
        onSubmit,
        values
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter `onChange` function. If you `console.log(typeof event.target.value)` it will be `string`.

```
const onChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: e.target.type === 'number' ? parseInt(e.target.value) : e.target.value });
};
```

Comment: I have just tried this, but they still return as strings in the console.

Comment: Actually, this works when the user enters a value in the fields. But, I still need to initialise the state as a number but I don't want it to be set to any value.

Comment: You have to allow nullable values in the server side then and set them as null in init of state in frontend.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have now got it working.

Comment: But it's not bad practice to allow nullable values to then check that the inputted value is not null upon submission for validation?